# Manipulate for loop batch file output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've below code which gives output correctly but I want each 3 lines output in single line. Please find code, current and desired output below:

```
For /R D:\workdir\src\ %%G IN (*.prt) do (echo %%G & echo %%~nG & ugpc %%G | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /i /c ".prt") >> test.csv
```

**Current output:**

[image: Current_Putput]

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what ugpc will output, <s>but the piped find couldn't pass a single integer</s>

Try this:

```
@Echo off
(For /R D:\workdir\src\ %%G IN (*.prt
    ) do For /f %%A in ('ugpc %%G ^|find.exe /i /c ".prt"') Do Echo(%%G,%%~nxG,%%A
) > test.csv
```

Comment: With above code, 1st and 3rd column is same. Actually `ugpc` returns the lines having string `.prt`. I'm interested in those line count. So had piped that output to return no. using code `| C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /i /c ".prt"`. I tried adding this code to your code but unable to get count in 3rd column.

Comment: OK, changed the answer to include your code, in a parsing for /f which uses a 2nd cmd behind the scenes the pipe symbol has to be escaped with a caret .

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!  As this is `for` loop, changed `>` to `>>` to append data.

Comment: I changed that intentionally, the outer parentheses will catch all output in a new file on every run, appending will afford resetting the file.